# Do Bosch dishwashers have a water temperature sensor?

Tags: dishwasher

My Bosch SMS65E12GB (Exxcel AquaStar 6.5L) dishwasher is running normally except that the dishes come out cold and not entirely clean.  No error codes are showing and the cycles take the usual length of time.  The diagnostic programme also came up with no errors.

My guess is that there is a temperature sensor which is faulty (reading high) and is causing the heating element to cut off too soon.  But I cannot find any mention of such a sensor either on Bosch's website or on 3rd party spares sites.  I can find the water flow, turbidity, salt level and rinse aid level sensors but not a temperature sensor.

Do these dishwashers have a temperature sensor?  Is it likely to be my problem?  If so any idea of where it is/part number would be most helpful.

Comment: There will be a temperature sensor, and the engineer in me says it will be close to the heater element so it can keep close control of the temperature.

Comment: Have you turned off heated dry?  Thats why my dishes come out hot, so something else to check.